# What should be format of payload to query siddhi to retrieve data with a where clause in Siddhi CEP

Tags: siddhi

I have used following code to insert data in a RDBMS using siddhi.

```
 @App:name("CustomerInfoCreator")
  @App:description("Consume events from HTTP and write to TEST_DB")

@source(type = 'http', receiver.url = "http://0.0.0.0:8006/production_cust_information",
    @map(type = 'json'))
define stream CustomerStream (id string, customerName string, cibil float, outsandingLoanAmt float, salary float, phoneNumber string, location string, status string, loanType string, loanAmt float, approvalDecision string);

@store(type='rdbms', jdbc.url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=samplesiddhi;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=false", username="sa", password="pwd", jdbc.driver.name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
define table CustomerLoanApplication  (id string, customerName string, cibil float, outsandingLoanAmt float, salary float, phoneNumber string, location string, status string, loanType string, loanAmt float, approvalDecision string);

-- Store all events to the table
@info(name = 'query1')
from CustomerStream
insert into CustomerLoanApplication

@App:description("Consume events from HTTP and write to TEST_DB")

@source(type = 'http', receiver.url = "http://0.0.0.0:8006/production_cust_information",
    @map(type = 'json'))
define stream CustomerStream (id string, customerName string, cibil float, outsandingLoanAmt float, salary float, phoneNumber string, location string, status string, loanType string, loanAmt float, approvalDecision string);

@store(type='rdbms', jdbc.url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=samplesiddhi;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=false", username="sa", password="$9Lserver", jdbc.driver.name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
define table CustomerLoanApplication  (id string, customerName string, cibil float, outsandingLoanAmt float, salary float, phoneNumber string, location string, status string, loanType string, loanAmt float, approvalDecision string);

-- Store all events to the table
@info(name = 'query1')
from CustomerStream
insert into CustomerLoanApplication
```

Inserted data in the table.

Now I wanted to retrieve the data from a REST API. I am able to fetch all records using following payload

```
POST: https://localhost:9743/query

{
   "appName":"CustomerInfoCreator",
   "query":"from  CustomerLoanApplication select * limit 10 "
}
```

But If I want to fetch the information with a where clause. So, I have used the following payload. But it throws an exception

```
POST : https://localhost:9743/query

{
   "appName":"CustomerInfoCreator",
   "query":"from  CustomerLoanApplication(phoneNumber = '587488848484') select * limit 10 "
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "type": "error",
    "message": "Cannot query: Error between @ Line: 1. Position: 0 and @ Line: 1. Position: 29. Syntax error in SiddhiQL, mismatched input '(' expecting <EOF>."
}
```

I did not find any documentation that provides and example for my need.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be corrected as

```
POST : https://localhost:9743/query

{
   "appName":"CustomerInfoCreator",
   "query":"from CustomerLoanApplication on phoneNumber = '587488848484' select * limit 10"
}
```